# Rake pipeline copy wrong images

Tags: rake, asset-pipeline

i have a simple AssetFile with the following

```
$: << 'lib'

require 'rake-pipeline'
require 'rake-pipeline-web-filters'   


output BUILD_DIR
input SRC_DIR do
  match '**/*.handlebars' do
    handlebars :precompile => true
    concat '0.js'
  end

  match '**/lib/*.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '1.js'
  end
  match '**/app.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '2.js'
  end
  match '**/controller/*.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '3.js'
  end
end

output ASSETS_JS
input BUILD_DIR do
  match '*.js' do
    concat 'app.js'
  end
end

output PUBLIC_ASSETS
input ASSETS do
  match '**/*' do
    copy
  end
end
```

all works fine except the last

```
output PUBLIC_ASSETS
input ASSETS do
  match '**/*' do
    copy
  end
end
```

that means copy all from ASSETS to PUBLIC_ASSETS, the files like .css and .js write fine and works but the images are corrupted in the copy process

example i have one image icons-nav.png with 3.06kb of size but after copy size is 3.09KB

i fount Rake::Pipeline an excelent tool for work but certainly gives more headaches than solutions, sometimes just throws random errors that is frustrating and the doc is really poor